# Search function stored procedure returning empty results

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to implement a stored procedure on a webpage. Initially a large table of data loads at bottom of the screen. At the top there are three available inputs the user can enter for a search on the table of data: Name, Course and Type.

However every time inputs (which are correct) are passed into the stored procedure I receive an empty object. I am certain the problem is in the stored procedure.

Any help would be great. Thanks

SQL

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAssessmentDefinitionTestSearch] 
    @AssessmentName         NVARCHAR(50),
    @CourseIdList           XML,
    @AssessmentMethodIdList XML,
    @UserId                 INT,
    @ClientId               INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
        ad.Id, ad.Name,
        am.Name AS Method,
        ad.GradebookMaxPoints,
        c.Name AS Course,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM Template t
         JOIN TemplateSection ts ON t.Id = ts.TemplateId
         JOIN TemplateSectionItem tsi ON ts.Id = tsi.TemplateSectionId
         WHERE t.Id = adt.TestTemplateId
           AND ts.IsActive = 1
           AND tsi.IsActive = 1) AS QuestionCount
    FROM 
        dbo.AssessmentDefinition ad
    JOIN 
        dbo.AssessmentDefinitionTest adt ON ad.Id = adt.Id
    JOIN 
        dbo.Course c ON ad.CourseId = c.Id
    JOIN 
        dbo.AssessmentMethod am ON ad.AssessmentTypeId = am.Id
    WHERE 
        ad.IsActive = 1
        AND ((ISNULL(@AssessmentName, '') = '') OR (ad.Name LIKE '%'+@AssessmentName+'%'))
        AND ((@CourseIdList IS NULL)
             OR (ad.CourseId IN (SELECT Id
                            FROM dbo.fnIntTableFromXML(@CourseIdList))))
        AND ((@AssessmentMethodIdList IS NULL)
             OR (ad.AssessmentTypeId IN (SELECT Id
                                         FROM dbo.fnIntTableFromXML(@AssessmentMethodIdList))))
        AND (@UserId = adt.OwnerUserId);
END;
```

Store

```
public async Task<List<AssessmentDTO>> SearchDefinition(AssessmentSearchDTO model)
{
    try
    {
        var courseIds = model?.Courses?.Select(x => x.Id)?.ToXMLString();
        var typeIds = model?.Types?.Select(x => x.Id)?.ToXMLString();
        var userId = _context.Authentication.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var clientId = _context.Authentication.User.Identity.GetClientId();

        var searchResults = await Db.spAssessmentDefinitionTestSearch(model.Name, courseIds, typeIds, userId, clientId).ToListAsync();

        var result = searchResults.Select(x => new AssessmentDTO
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Course = x.Course,
            Type = x.Method
        }).ToList();

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
           <label>Name</label>
           <input ng-model="searchCriteria.Name" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label>Course</label>
            <select ng-model="searchCriteria.Courses" id="" class="form-control" ng-options="type as type.Name for type in Courses"></select>
     </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
                 <label>Type</label>
                 <select ng-model="searchCriteria.Types" id="" class="form-control" ng-options="type as type.Name for type in Types"></select>
       </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
   <button class="btn btn-search full-width btn-full-width btn-primary" style="height:100%;" ng-click="searchDefinition(searchCriteria.Name, searchCriteria.Courses, searchCriteria.Types)" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
</div>
        <!-- This uses a directive -->
    <bs-paginated-table list="assessments"
                        sortable="true"
                        default-display-num="20"
                        initial-predicate="'Course'"
                        show-display-select="true"
                        show-filter="true"
                        inline-edit="'none'"
                        columns="DefinitionColumns"
                        buttons="DefinitionButtons"
                        empty-results-message="'Well, it looks like there\'s no results to match those terms...'"></bs-paginated-table>
```

AngularCtrl

```
    $scope.searchCriteria = searchCriteria.data;
    $scope.searchDefinition = function (Name, Course, Type) {
        if (!$scope.searchCriteria) {
            $scope.searchCriteria = {};
        }
        toastr.info('Searching Assessments...', {
            timeOut: 3,
            extendedTimeout: 1
        });

        var newSearch = {
            Name: $scope.searchCriteria.Name,
            Courses: $scope.searchCriteria.Courses,
            Types: $scope.searchCriteria.Types
        };

        console.log(newSearch);
        assessmentControllerService.searchDefinition(newSearch)
            .then(
                function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.assessments = data.data;
                    if ($scope.searchCallback) {
                        $scope.searchCallback($scope.assessments);
                    }
                    $scope.loadingResults = false;
                },
                function (errCallback) {
                    bootbox.alert("An error has occurred.");
                })
    };
```

Comment: So does the procedure return results? I mean at this point about all we can do is try to teach you how to debug this. We have no data to work with.

Comment: Try testing the SP in ssms with user inputs.

Comment: Ya I realize that is an issue. No it returns an empty object

Comment: If I provided the tables and column info, would that help you analyze the query? Testing in ssms rn and have no idea am getting nothing

Comment: So the procedure returns no rows? That means you don't have any data that matches the criteria os that query. You are going to have to figure this out. We can't do that from here.